# Prove that the differential of the map is injective .

Tags: periodic-functions, differential

I have the following map, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ given by $f(\theta) = (cos\theta, sin\theta)$.
The differential of the map is $$df_\theta(\partial_\theta) = -\sin \theta \partial_1 + \cos \theta \partial_2$$, where $\partial_{1,2}$ denote differentitial w.r.t $x_1,x_2$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

The answer says that the differential is non-zero for all $\theta$ and so it's injective for all $\theta$. I don't understand why it is injective since it is a periodic function. Probably I am missing something trivial but I don't see what.

Comment: $df_\theta$ is injective as a map between the tangent spaces, so the periodicity does not matter. Check that if $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then $df_\theta(a \partial_\theta) = 0$ implies $a = 0$

Comment: @Fra Thank you for your reply ! So I don't need to check when $-\sin \theta + \cos\theta$ is zero, but rather if $(-\sin \theta, \cos\theta)$ have common zeros, as they don't and the rank of the differential is indeed 1, the map is injective?

Comment: Yes exactly! You are welcome:)